# Fancybox Iframe waiting upload Files

Tags: jquery, fancybox

I trying submit a picture in a Iframe (fancybox), but if I close the iframe I don't get the Data on the server.

(this code are inside the frame)

```
<a class="button" id="finishButton" onclick="closeME()"><span>@PhotoPremier.Resources.Global.btnSubmit</span></a>

<script>
function closeME() {
    if (ValidationToSubmit() == true) {
        $('#FormToSubmit').submit();
    }
}

$('#FormToSubmit').submit(function() {
    event.preventDefault();
    parent.$.fancybox.close();
});​
</script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My workaround is very simple and a little creative.

I redirect to a simples page (for me a create a shared page [MVC], for used in all situation) and this page get the new URL and by javascript redirect to new destination and closed the iframe.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
if("@ViewBag.Url" != "False")
{
    window.parent.location.href = "@ViewBag.Url";
}
parent.$.fancybox.close();
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

The point is that you have to wait 'till the post finishes successfully and only after that you can close the iframe.

Do you have the ability to edit the server side of the file upload response? If yes then just do the regular submit and on the response print:

```
<script>parent.$.fancybox.close();</script>
```

You can also try to submit the form via [jQuery.post](http://docs.jquery.com/Post) and on success close the iframe, but this might not work for file upload:

```
<a class="button" id="finishButton" onclick="submit()"><span>@PhotoPremier.Resources.Global.btnSubmit</span></a>

<script>
$('#FormToSubmit').submit(submit);

function submit() {
    if (!ValidationToSubmit()) {
        return;
    }
    var data = {
        x: $("#x").val(),
        y: $("#y").val(),
        ...
    };
    $.post({
        url:"...",
        data: data,
        success: function(){
            parent.$.fancybox.close();
        }
    })
}
</script>
```

unfortunatelly you'll have to prepare the data object to be posted, but if you have a few fields, it shouldn't be a problem.

Comment: ups, I didn't realize you want to upload a file. I added a new idea, see if that is possible in your case.